# Sorting function is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of object, which is actually getting fetched from backend, now I'm mapping data and want to sort it in ascending and descending order on click of a button, so I made a onSort function, but it is not working as I expected, as, uppercase and lowercase problem is there, even being alphabetically in between, lowercase are getting shown at the end, numbers are not getting sorted, and there is another column which shows the amount like '$100', but due to that dollar sign, function takes it as a string and sort it.

**this is like**

*$110, $12, $24000, $2500, $3*

**it should be like**

*$3, $12, $110, $2500, $24000*

**for column with upper and lowercase elements its like, in ascending order -**

*Apple
Banana,
Dog,
ant,
candy*

**where is should be like -**

*ant, Apple, Banana, candy, Dog*

In case of numbers its like - 112,12,141,21,32,345,35;

where it should be like - 12,21,32,35,112,141,345;

here the code snippets I used,

```
const [sort, setSort] = usestate("asc")
const onSort = (obj: string) => {
    
    if (sort === "asc") {
      const tableEl= [...tstate.tableItem].sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        if (a[obj].split('/').reverse().join() > b[obj].split('/').reverse().join()) return 1;
        else if (b[obj].split('/').reverse().join() > a[obj].split('/').reverse().join()) return -1;
        else return 0;
        // return a[obj] > b[obj] ? 1 : -1;
      });
      setTableState({
        ...tstate,
        tableItem: tableEl,
      });
      setSort("dsc")
    }
    if (sort === "dsc") {
      const tableEl= [...tstate.tableItem].sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        if (b[obj].split('/').reverse().join() > a[obj].split('/').reverse().join()) return 1;
        else if (a[obj].split('/').reverse().join() > b[obj].split('/').reverse().join()) return -1;
        else return 0;
        // return b[obj] > a[obj] ? 1 : -1;
      });
      setTableState({
        ...tstate,
        tableItem: tableEl,
      });
      setSort("asc")
    }
  };
```

Comment: That's because `'a'>'A'` is `true`. If it's number, change it to number using `Number()`. Oher wise it will take it as a string.

Comment: Can you share some code for both cases?

Comment: Please read [ask] provide a [mcve]. If the problem is the sorting then you should be able to reduce this to some sample input (which you haven't provided in the form of code) and some JavaScript which focuses on the problem (and doesn't include any of the React stuff around it).

Answer (score 1):

Use [localCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method to check for case sensitivity. Since you want to check for the numbers use [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) method.

```
function compare(a, b) {
    if ( isNaN(Number(a) || isNaN(Number(b) )) {
        return b.localeCompare(a)
    } else {
        if (Number(a)>Number(b)) return 1
        else if (Number(a)<Number(b)) return -1
        else return 0
    }
}
```

Now use this function in the sort method

```
[...tstate.tableItem].sort(compare)
```

Comment: This is working in all cases except one, in that column I'm getting amount where it has a dollar sign before the amount(i.e., the numeric value), now with dollar sign, it acts as a string and gets wrongly sort.

Comment: @PrajulAaditya yes, if any of the value includes symbol, it will be treated as string. If you know the possible symbols, remove them before passing into the sorting function. (You can use regex to find the symbols)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, regex worked fine, but only issue it created is, its ignoring the '-' sign. i.e., the negative values.


const stripNonNumberRegex = /[^_\d]/g;

let arr: string[] = ['$112', '$12', '$141', '$21', '$32', '$-345', '$35'];

arr.sort((a: any, b: any) => {

  const a1 = a.replace(stripNonNumberRegex, '');

  const b1 = b.replace(stripNonNumberRegex, '');

  return a1 - b1;
});

Answer (score 1):

When sorting an array of `string` values, you can use a custom [`compareFn` argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#comparefn) for `array.sort()`.

In the code sample below I give an example of using the return value of [`string.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with custom options (which are detailed at the reference page for the [`Intl.Collator()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator#options)).

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMUQ1gNwKYGU4BOUiAFAIYBciAzlASgOYA0iARlbfWAwJRVggAtq2wFEAbwCwAKESIA9PMQAbbGUyNEUABYxqiAAbgAJtmApsxg4hDVs+ndkSngZEMuLK4EMqplyIBFoVb19sKgAFMgIyQWwoUWoAHk5GAG0Aci8fVQBhOEEAB2jsDIBdAD40gEYyxABeGzAXC2MAbhl-RECwYLhC2CDI6Nj4xJS6dKzQvILiglLKtIAmOsapWTlEATj6CCo6EGwmLrk7XowYDSgATyoM1jI7DJPNgF8O6S6FtAIkMgAdNkwvkiiUSKwWMDVCx+oNejxPm9OtJVMRogQOJNuGk1ohMgBBQqFVQvRAZABCZDA1LIZIyABE4Ax6dSoPSfM0buVPhiAdRCFASCg0JccPgiIiZD0BaogczyAQCIiFEo0gAiNnqljqokk7DaxDqqk0mmG9Wc4w3c1MhjqsoojENfEZarVZb092egAs1Xpyz9LAyAGYPUHg96AKz04PRsq8pX8wXC1DoLB4QVS6QyuByrwMRXKtqq-Hq93mgPm0NVyPmt3LOu+qtR+0yIA)

```ts
function intuitiveSort (a: string, b: string): number {
  // leaving this `undefined` uses the default locale
  const locale: Parameters<string['localeCompare']>[1] = undefined;

  const options: Parameters<string['localeCompare']>[2] = {
    numeric: true,
    sensitivity: 'base',
  };

  return a.localeCompare(b, locale, options);
}

let arr: string[] = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Dog', 'ant', 'candy'];
arr.sort(intuitiveSort);
console.log(arr); // ["ant", "Apple", "Banana", "candy", "Dog"]

arr = ['112', '12', '141', '21', '32', '345', '35'];
arr.sort(intuitiveSort);
console.log(arr); // ["12", "21", "32", "35", "112", "141", "345"]
```

Compiled JS from the TS Playground link above:

```js
"use strict";
function intuitiveSort(a, b) {
    // leaving this `undefined` uses the default locale
    const locale = undefined;
    const options = {
        numeric: true,
        sensitivity: 'base',
    };
    return a.localeCompare(b, locale, options);
}
let arr = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Dog', 'ant', 'candy'];
arr.sort(intuitiveSort);
console.log(arr); // ["ant", "Apple", "Banana", "candy", "Dog"]
arr = ['112', '12', '141', '21', '32', '345', '35'];
arr.sort(intuitiveSort);
console.log(arr); // ["12", "21", "32", "35", "112", "141", "345"]
```

Comment: Thank you, now my project is working as expected.

Comment: It did answer my question, but I'm using another method, because I also need to sort the one with symbol.