# Sort child divs alphanumerically

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to sort some child divs under a parent div. The child divs has alphanumeric id.
For example: `"1_tango" , "5_charlie", "unassigned"`.

For the above example, the sort result should be:

```
"unassigned" , "1_tango" , "5_charlie",
```

The code I am using from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery):

```
var mylist = $(this.sub_group_drop_zone);
var listitems = mylist.children('div').get();
listitems.sort(function (a, b) {
    var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
    var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
    return (compA > compB) ? -1 : (compB > compA) ? 1 : 0;
   })
$(mylist).append(listitems);
```

However this results in :

```
"unassigned", "5_charlie", "1_tango", "3_Beta" ..
```

How can I fix that. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) which can be made case-insensitive and offers numeric sorting options.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71923995/438273) for an example of using [`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

Comment: I am not using string array or list. Here listitmes are list of jquery elements.

Comment: @jsejcksn 
did not work :( 
" " "
listitems.sort(function (a, b) {
        const locale = undefined;
        const options = {
          numeric: true,
          sensitivity: 'base',
        };
        return $(b).text().localeCompare($(a).text(), locale, options);
      })
" " "

Comment: @pilchard 
I have seen and tried localCompare. An example suits my case would be nice.

Comment: `listitems.sort((a, b) => $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text(), { sensitivity: 'base' }));`

Comment: @pilchard unfortunately does not work either. Just removed the `numeric: true` . from the option.

Comment: What 'doesn't work' ? To sort `unassigned` first you'll need a second comparison. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5h8joxu/)

Comment: @pilchard 
Yes, in your shared fiddle, output looks correct. Now I have to adapt to them jquery element list instead of normal string list. Sorry I am new to javascript/typescript.

Comment: I mocked the jquery `$()` function so you should be able to use the sort method directly.

Comment: @pilchard unfortunately, in javascript it works. but in typescript, it complains.

`The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)
`

Comment: Ah, that's just because I didn't explicitly convert the booleans before subtracting. you can simply use the [unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) to convert each before subtracting `+($(b).text() === 'unassigned') - +($(a).text() === 'unassigned')`. [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxcu3z4v/) and [TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOP4RN)

Comment: @pilchard previous error is solved with unary plus. Now only one error left with sensitivity parameter.
` Argument of type '{ sensitivity: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | string[] | undefined'.
`

Comment: yes, i forgot the second parameter is actually locale and the third is options(`localeCompare(compareString, locales, options)`), it should read `$(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text(), undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' })` passing undefined here as `locale` but if you prefer a locale then you can pass it, ie `$(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text(), 'en', { sensitivity: 'base' })` for 'english'

Comment: thanks a lot , now it's  working as expected. :)

Comment: Great, glad you got it working!